# Regex always returns false on keyup

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to validate input after every keypress. To do this i have the following code:

```
var passwordMain = $('#reg-password-one'),
        regExOne = new RegExp('A-Z');

    passwordMain.keyup(function(){
        console.log(regExOne.test(passwordMain.val()))
    })
```

The out put is always false when i try "ABC"

Am i looking at this in the wrong way?

Comment: You seem to be missing a character class. `[A-Z]`

Comment: what are you trying to test?

Comment: Thank you, such a simple mistake. Now works with [ ]

Comment: If you wish to confirm that the user only uses uppercase letters, you need `[A-Z]+` where the plus (+) sign indices that at least 1 instance of the character class is required

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your current regex mean literally `A-Z`.

To allow only upper case letters, you need to put it in characters group.

```
[A-Z]
```

But that will only allow single letter. To allow multiple letters, you must also append quantifier. It may be [`?`/`+`/`{n,m}`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374(v=vs.110).aspx). So in your case it would be `{6,}` to allow more than 6 symbols entered for stronger password.

In the end your regex is

```
/[A-Z]{6,32}/
```